# Load more workflow with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

What would be the proper way to implement "Load more" in a recyclerView using Parse.

I am querying for objects with a limit of 10, when clicking a load more button, I have to load 10 objects everytime.

I'm sure some of you have implemented this kind of behavior with Parse, so I'm looking for a heads up on how to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `setSkip()` and increase it with every query.

First query:

```
query.setLimit(10);
```

Second query:

```
query.setLimit(10);
query.setSkip(10);
```

Third query:

```
query.setLimit(10);
query.setSkip(20);
```